# Google Sign In Failed - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I followed this [tutorial](http://androidcodes.info/home/main/android-sign-in-using-google-firebase-auth-no-server-required-free/) and in this part of the code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Google Sign In Failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting a google sign in failed. I do not know what is wrong how to fix?

I actually got in working when I tried running app-released.apk instead of running in directly on my phone.

Answer (score 2):

> Google sign-in is automatically configured on your connected iOS and
>   web apps. To set up Google sign-in for your Android apps, you need to
>   add the SHA1 fingerprint for each app on your Project Settings.

See this page for information on using keytool to get the SHA hash of your signing certificate

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Go to Project - Settings - General to add the fingerprint.

To get the SHA1 debug fingerprint (if you are debugging you only need this one):

```
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\<username>\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

To get the SHA1 release fingerprint:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias <MYKEYNAME> -keystore C:\mykeylocation\keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented Google Signin in my project. Here is the code.

**GoogleLoginActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

import in.invis.organickerala.R;
import in.invis.organickerala.activities.BaseActivity;

public class GoogleLoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;



    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    // [START declare_auth_listener]
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    // [END declare_auth_listener]

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private TextView mDetailTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        mDetailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.login_with_google).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);


        // [START config_signin]
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END config_signin]

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // [START initialize_auth]
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]

        // [START auth_state_listener]
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(user);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };
        // [END auth_state_listener]
    }

    // [START on_start_add_listener]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    // [END on_start_add_listener]

    // [START on_stop_remove_listener]
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
    // [END on_stop_remove_listener]

    // [START onactivityresult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }
    }
    // [END onactivityresult]

    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        showProgressDialog();

        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(GoogleLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressDialog();

                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END auth_with_google]

    // [START signin]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signin]

    private void signOut() {
        // Firebase sign out
        mAuth.signOut();

        // Google sign out
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        // Firebase sign out
        mAuth.signOut();

        // Google revoke access
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.google_status_fmt, user.getEmail()));
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            signIn();
        } else if (i == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            signOut();
        } else if (i == R.id.disconnect_button) {
            revokeAccess();
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity.java**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import in.invis.organickerala.R;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @VisibleForTesting
    public ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        hideProgressDialog();
    }

}

**activity_google.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.FirebaseIcon"
            android:id="@+id/google_icon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_firebase_lockup"
            android:src="@drawable/firebase_lockup_400"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_bottom_margin"
            android:text="@string/google_title_text"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
            android:text="@string/signed_out" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
            tools:text="Firebase User ID: 123456789abc" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/grey_300">

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_out_and_disconnect"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/sign_out"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/disconnect_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/disconnect"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First verify if your project is properly configured in API console.
Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) link as reference (some people say that you should use .json generated in this link, cause the one from console does not work).

Another thing, did "account picker screen" was displayed? Can you print status, and status code tou received?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you messed up/haven't configured your debug certificate (might happen if you switch to another development machine with different keystore set). 
Make sure you have **added the SHA1 certificate fingerprint** in the Firebase Console Settings section of your project, as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#before_you_begin

Comment: This happened to me when changing development PCs. A new debug key was created causing authentication to fail. Make sure all SHA1 fingerprints are added in Firebase. Nasty "bug" to track down...