# Firebase security against modified APK and MITM attacks

Tags: android, firebase, security, firebase-security

I want to know how secure Firebase is against the below-mentioned attack.

1. App Modification - I know Firebase uses SHA-1, SHA-256 protection against Authentication, But if modified app bypasses the login process, does this also prevents attacks against read-write in both databases due to SHA.
2. If the unencrypted data flow is accessed by an attacker due to CA certificates installed in the device. Can he change database queries?

Comment: 1. Are you talking about that you have to register an app by it's SHA hash? 2. If you have access to the transferred data of course you can change database queries. Therefore it is important to limit each user to her/his data on database level and not only within the app.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
1. Yes, SHA hash of signing certificate and when App is signed with different certificate then login fails, As shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200674/google-sign-in-failed-firebase, I just wondered if database queries also failed on signing with different certificate.
2. Too bad. I just assumed if firebase is recognizing its authentication queries with signing certificate hash, it might have used some digital signing or encryption besides TLS to protect against MITM.

Comment: Applying protection on the app is the wrong way. No matter what you implement there is someone who can crack it. Use user authentication of Firebase level and apply Firebase Security Rules to protect the all the data in the Firebase data store.

Comment: Nice advice, even if features mentioned in question exists, still these will work as defense in depth mechanism